# jQuery removing class on resize not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm really confused right now, I think my code is okay but the class doesn't seem to be removed. I've tried alerting when the window is resized less than 600px and it worked but can't seem to remove the class. The class I want to remove is the .darkheader class which triggers the header shrinking effect. I want to remove to remove that effect when the window is resized to tablet or mobile size.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>IT'S RENDELL</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <nav>
        <header class="clearHeader">
            <ul>
                <li>Blog<li>
                <li>My works<li>
                <li>Resume</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </header>
    </nav>

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1 
/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
  height: 2000px;
}

.clearHeader{
height: 100px; 
background: #CF000F;
position: fixed;
top:200;
width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s;
-o-transition: all 0.4s;
transition: all 0.4s;
}

.clearHeader ul{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.clearHeader ul li{
   display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
   font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Tahoma
}

.darkHeader {height: 50px;}
.darkHeader ul {line-height: 50px;}

.wrapper {
height:2000px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
});

$(window).resize(function(){
     if($(this).width() < 600){
        return $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
     }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing 'this' with 'window'?

Comment: yea, but still won't work.

Comment: Is there a reason you are returning the .removeClass() ?

Comment: I'm not really sure since I just copied some snippets from other forums with solved issues hoping mine would be solved too.

Comment: it works fine in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rb7vLmet/

Comment: When the window is scrolled down the header shrinks, but if the window is then resized to be small it expands again. Is this the desired effect?

Comment: Yeah, it works as what that code should. You wanna achieve something different?

Comment: It's like this, I want to remove the class if the window is resized so the header becomes static and the shrinking effect on scroll will not trigger anymore. The reason is that I want to style the navigation like the one in bootstrap where the menus are hidden and will only appear if a button is clicked. I didn't want it to have that shrinking effect when the window is on mobile or tablet size because it would be pretty annoying.

Comment: I only want the header to shrink on full screen window. But on resize, it's a different header style without the shrinking effect.

Comment: I think my question is quite confusing, I'm really sorry about that.

Comment: So you need to check the `width` in `scroll` function and if it less than 600 then dont do `addClass` like `if ((scroll >= 500) && ($(this).width() > 600))`  Is that what u want?

Comment: Ok, again,  this is the only problem I have, I just want to remove that shrinking effect when my browser is resized or the window is a tablet or mobile size. Meaning I want my header to not have the shrinking effect if the window is resized. I have no problem with the scrolling function at all.

Comment: I want to check the width in the window. Like, I'm trying to create a responsive navbar. But before that, I want to remove the class which triggers the shrinking effect when the window is resized.

Comment: it's like I want to turn of the shrinking effect if my browser is resized to like 600px.

Comment: Using jQuery.   Bleh.  Have we considered media queries, which would just work: `@media (max-width: 600px) { . clearHeader {transition:none;} }`?

Comment: @John Green That seems to only remove the transition, not the entire shrinking itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "return" in the resize function